# help with grep regular expresion/subexpression

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expression

Hey I have a problem with regular subexpresions.

```
grep -o ".*='.*'" parameters.txt
```

`parameters.txt` includes:

```
name='something'
lastname=' 123123'
something='   somethinggg'
```

My regular expresion returns everything, but i want it to return only name and value without `=` and `' '`. I also want it to be immune to spaces and tabulators.

```
name something
lastname 123123
somethign somethinggg
```

Comment: Is the right hand side guaranteed to always be single quoted? Can the value to the right of `=` also contain `=`-characters? What does the "immunity" actually mean? Does it mean you want to allow the line to be indented by spaces or tabs (should the indentation be preserved in that case?), or does it mean you want to maintain any spaces or tabs in the values to the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I would recommend using `sed` instead:

```
sed -r "/^[^=]*$/d;t;s/=/ /;s/'//g;s/[\t ]+/ /g" parameters.txt
```

This command

- skips any line *not* containing an `=` sign
- replaces *the first* `=` by a space (leaving it open that the "value" part may itself contain an assignment)
- replaces any single quotes `'` by nothing
- replaces any multiple tabs and spaces by one single space

Comment: Maybe `s/=/ /g` should not have the `g`.

Comment: You are right, it is unnecessary there and would break things if the argument also contained an `=` sign.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/['\''=]/ /g;s/  */ /g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ tr '=' ' ' < parameters.txt  | sed "s,',,g"  | sed -E "s,\s+, ,g"
name something
lastname 123123
something somethinggg
```

Comment: You can nearly always combine two `sed` commands into one. Many `sed` dialects do not support the Perl escape `\s` (try `[[:space:]]` for a portable equivalent). Also, notice that `sed` has a `y` command; but replacing *all* equals slgns will wreck any value which contains a literal equals sign.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl:

```
perl -pe "tr/=' \t/ /d"   parameters.txt
```